# What is the best way to handle empty [input type=date] cross-browser?

Tags: html, forms, date, date-formatting

I'm working on a web app at the moment which uses the HTML5 `[input type=date]` form element. As far as I know it's only supported in a few browsers at the moment: Chrome, Safari and Opera.

I'm focussing on support for Chrome and Safari primarily. I'm trying to detect whether a date has been entered or not but Chrome and Safari both treat blank dates differently. To Chrome, an empty date field's value is an empty string, but to Safari an empty date field's value is `'0000-00-00'`.

Is there any standard for detecting blank dates or am I just going to have to test as many different 'blank' formats as I can? I'd rather not since going forward I'd hate to have to keep adding formats to the list once other browsers like IE and Firefox support `[input type=date]` and go with their own blank format again....

Comment: It sounds a bug of Safari. What version of Safari?

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 for Windows. I know it's no longer officially updated but clients want support for it so unfortunately I can't just ignore it. I checked it on iPad and it works like Chrome so it appears to only affect the desktop version at least.